# How to set a page as the index page

Tags: cakephp

I am new to Cake PHP, in regular PHP I had a index.php and for any bad url tried it would just show home. In Cake, I am switching an old PHP and HTML website to use Cake PHP. I already successfully converted one page  :(. Which is good but that page is just about_us. I have not done Home (which would be index.php). So here is my scenario

I created all the controllers and models with no code in it except for this one page that gets a bunch of products,but I have the following questions as I do not understand CakePHP documentation:

1) How can I set up an index.php page and where should I put it and Actually this page needs to grab something from the db too. Should it go under views/pages? (i am not sure)

2) Also how do i retrieve parameters in Cake PHP? i used to have   `index.php?name=blah` and just pull name in. I am not too clear on how the cake website says to do it.. you just add the parameter after a /index/2 for example? How come?.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think cake is quite well-documented. You just didn't take enough time to read the book.
1) If you want to create a 'Home' page, it doesn't have to be an 'index.php' file.
(cake has some index.php file to call the bootstrap and dispatch logic and don't mess with them)
You can
- create a view (some .ctp file), put it to /app/View/Pages/ so you can use the url '/pages/' to access the page. Or you can edit /app/Config/route.php file to connect the page to whatever path you want
- create a normal controller/action/view (if you need to grab something from the db so you should have some models, your controller will call the models and pass data to the view). You can edit /app/Config/route.php to connect the page with your path.

Cake is convention-over-configuration. But you should understand both the convention and the configuration.  Read the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/876/The-Manual). Learn more about MVC, about cake's convention and mechanism.

2) You can retrieve the parameter from controller or view (you should do it in the controller) by using $this->param or $this->passedArgs. There are named ones (e.g: profile/name:john) and unnamed ones (e.g: profile/john).